I'm starting to learn Compose. I want to know how to make a single swipe animation when I press a button
I'm making a custom calendar for a daily planner and I want the calendar to swipe left or right when changing months.enter image description here
I tried to implement this through coroutines and a delay between exit and enter transitions of AnimatedVisibility, but this method seems wrong and buggy to me. To avoid overloading the code, I made a small application with the same animation implementation.
val animDuration = 100
var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

//Required for variable transitions for each button
val enterTransition = remember { mutableStateOf(EnterTransition.None) }
val exitTransition = remember { mutableStateOf(ExitTransition.None) }

val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {

    ButtonLeft {
        // Here I change the initialOffsetX of the enter transition
        // and the targetOffsetX of the exit transition
        // so that the RedBox goes to the right and appears on the left.

        enterTransition.value = slideInHorizontally(
            initialOffsetX = { -2*it },
            animationSpec = tween(animDuration, easing = LinearEasing)
        )
        exitTransition.value = slideOutHorizontally(
            targetOffsetX = { 2*it },
            animationSpec = tween(animDuration, easing = LinearEasing)
        )

        // Here I turn off RedBox visibility,
        // wait for the animation end with a delay,
        // and then turn on visibility
        coroutineScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.Main) {
            visible = false
            delay(200)
            visible = true
        }
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = visible,
        enter = enterTransition.value + fadeIn(tween(animDuration)),
        exit = exitTransition.value + fadeOut(tween(animDuration))
    ) {
        RedBox()
    }

    ButtonRight {

        // Here RedBox goes to the left and appears on the right.

        enterTransition.value = slideInHorizontally(
            initialOffsetX = { 2*it },
            animationSpec = tween(animDuration, easing = LinearEasing)
        )
        exitTransition.value = slideOutHorizontally(
            targetOffsetX = { -2*it },
            animationSpec = tween(animDuration, easing = LinearEasing)
        )

        coroutineScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.Main) {
            visible = false
            delay(200)
            visible = true
        }
    }
}


Try using HorizontalPager for this

TY, hope this help me

Take a look at this for reference
